# What do the * and & operators operate on if the argument is complex?

Tags: c++, c, language-features, operator-keyword

Simply, is

```
&someObject->someAttribute.someMember;
```

equivalent to

```
&(someObject->someAttribute.someMember);
```

or

```
(&someObject)->someAttribute.someMember;
```

or

```
(&(someObject->someAttribute)).someMember;
```

Or should you really put explicit parenthesis there just to be safe?

Comment: see here: http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/operator_precedence

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is equivalent to:

```
&((someObject->someAttribute).someMember)
```

The `->` and `.` have equal precedence and are left-associative.  The unary-`&` has lower precedence.

If you have very complex expressions, then you should certainly use parentheses to group things and clarify your code.  This isn't particularly complex, though; it is quite common to see code like this in C and C++.

Answer (score 3):

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)

Scroll down to the operators section.  Operators in a higher box in the chart are considered before operators in a lower box.  Also see the rules for associativity.

> Or should you really put explicit parenthesis there just to be safe?

This is somewhat of a preference issue but as a general rule, if you're having any trouble figuring it out, then someone else will too. Put parenthesis when in doubt.

Comment: -1 because you didn't actually answer the question, and it was a simple straightforward question.  This should have been a comment instead of a reputation-fishing expedition. See Martin York's comment for an example.

Comment: @John: A bit harsh for such a new user.  Teaching to fish is important too, and even preferable in some cases.

Comment: @Roger:  You're probably right.  @dgnorton:  Sorry for the harshness.  I've undone my d/v.

Answer (score 0):

If u want address of the someMember then &(someObject->someAttribute.someMember) OR &someObject->someAttribute.someMember.

First someObject->someAttribute and second to its member somMember and third is &
address

struct xxx{
        int xx;
 };
 struct temp{
        int x;
        struct xxx ptr;
 };

```
    struct temp t1 = {125,{127}};
    struct temp *t2 = &t1;
    printf("%d %d",t2->x,*&t2->ptr.xx);
```